# Server 2012, auditing GPO changes?

Tags: group-policy

How does one find audit information about individual settings within a GPO?

I've been searching and have hit a wall at "enabling advanced audit policy configuration" and enabled the Create/Delete auditing for groupPolicyContainerObjects in the SACL for the domain.

Comment: In the Sysvol folder you can use the GPO folder timestamp too.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - there isn't auditing for individual components of a GPO. Even if you enable the advanced audit policy configuration and get it working 100% correctly (which can be a challenge in and of itself) it will only give you the GUID of the policy in question. It doesn't provide a friendly name or any kind of details as to what has changed. At best you can puzzle out who changed what policy.

If you really want to get your hands on something in this vein I would suggest getting the auditing enabled (so you have a history if someone changes it outside of change control) and a product like [AGPM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hh826067.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I did find that with powershell I can export GPO objects as xml or html, and by running a comparison on the exported files I can see what has changed. This should let me at least know if *something has changed*.